# How to inject vault variables into Ansible template

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

*It's possible this can be explained via Ansible docs however looking for the solution to this has yielded different results, all of which have failed for me.*

I am trying to setup an Ansible role to handle installation of Airflow on a remote AWS instance. I am using Ansible v2.9.11.
Part of the role involves transferring a .cfg template file where sensitive values need to be plugged in from the Ansible vault, such as passwords.

Current ansible directory structure:

```
- repo_parent
  \- group_vars
   \- nonprod
     |- plaintext (plaintext values)
     |- vault     (encrypted values)
  \- roles
   \- airflow
    \- tasks
      |- main.yml
      |- install.yml
    \- templates
      |- airflow.cfg.j2
```

For this example, I'm going to reference `airflow_conf_dir`. The `airflow.cfg.j2` template has the following line:

`airflow_home = {{ airflow_conf_dir }}`

`airflow_conf_dir` is defined in plaintext and vault as shown: (placeholder values)

`airflow_conf_dir: x/y/airflow/conf`

====================================================================================

When dry-running the playbook,

`ansible-playbook test.yml --ask-vault-pass --user <USER_OMITTED> --key-file "~/.ssh/id_rsa" --tags "airflow" --check`

I keep running into this error

```
failed: [<IP_OMITTED>] (item={'src': 'airflow.cfg.j2', 'dest': '/x/y/airflow/conf/airflow.cfg'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"dest": "/x/y/airflow/conf/airflow.cfg", "src": "airflow.cfg.j2"}, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'airflow_conf_dir' is undefined"}
```

The only workaround for this is declaring the variables in the role directly. Ex:

```
- name: Create Airflow config files
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    owner: user
    group: group
  vars:
    airflow_conf_dir: x/y/airflow/conf
  with_items:
    - { src: 'airflow.cfg.j2', dest: '/x/y/airflow/conf/airflow.cfg' }
  tags:
    - airflow
    - airflow_config
```

This is problematic because then I'm forced to store sensitive data openly in the tasks themselves. How do I reference values stored in vault/plaintext and apply them to the template?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was staring me in the face the whole time. I needed to include

```
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/nonprod/vault
    - group_vars/nonprod/plaintext
```

into the playbook itself